# How do I make my cursor return to its normal size?

Tags: macos, mouse, trackpad

Apparently because of either some BetterTouchTool shortcut or bug<sup>1</sup> I have a gigantic mouse cursor, and I can't reverse it.  BetterTouchTool has the option to toggle the cursor size, but instead of going back and forth between normal and larger, it just gets larger and larger and larger.  This is driving me crazy and can only be fixed by rebooting, as far as I know.

I need some way of restoring the mouse cursor to its original dimensions.  How can I do this?

---

<sup>1</sup> In the past I used BTT's ability to toggle mouse cursor size to visually signal that my shortcuts were working.  But now something is doing that without my knowledge or consent.

I've searched through all of my BetterTouchTool shortcuts and I can't find one causing the problem, so it may be a bug in the software itself, or it may be a result of a combination of lacking a good enough search engine and me somehow overlooking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try: System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display ->  Cursor -> Cursor size

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, choose Apple > System Preferences, then tap Universal Access.

Click Monitor, click Cursor, then drag the Cursor Size slider to the right to increase the size.

Tip. To temporarily increase the pointer, quickly move your finger over the trackpad or make a quick motion with your mouse. To turn this feature off, uncheck the "Shake the mouse cursor to show where it is" box in the Cursor panel under Universal Access settings.

Comment: This applies to older versions of macOS/OS X